Problem with Composite Primary Keys in JPA (Migrating from hibernate-jpa 2.1 to jakarta-persistence 3.1.0)
Currently updating a Java Spring Boot application from spring-boot 1.5.11.RELEASE to spring-boot 3.3.1 and now I'm facing some problems while launching my app, since I had to update hibernate-jpa 2.1 lib to jakarta-persistence 3.1.0
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.asBasicValuedModelPart()" because "subPart" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at br.com.xbrain.iam.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.asBasicValuedModelPart()" because "subPart" is null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ModelPart.asBasicValuedModelPart()" because "subPart" is null
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractDomainPath.addSortSpecification(AbstractDomainPath.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractDomainPath.apply(AbstractDomainPath.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.AbstractDomainPath.apply(AbstractDomainPath.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.ordering.OrderByFragmentImpl.apply(OrderByFragmentImpl.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.applyOrdering(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:752) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.applyOrdering(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:734) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.generateSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:530) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.createSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionLoaderSingleKey.<init>(CollectionLoaderSingleKey.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.createSingleKeyCollectionLoader(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:814) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.createNamedQueryCollectionLoader(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:642) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4783) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1506) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

Here's my code:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_hierarchy")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserHierarchy {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserHierarchyPk userHierarchyPk;

    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_hierarchy_user"),
        referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_leader", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_hierarchy_leader"),
        referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User userLeader;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"user", "userLeader"})
@Embeddable
public class UserHierarchyPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "fk_user", nullable = false)
    private Integer user;

    @Column(name = "fk_user_leader", nullable = false)
    private Integer userLeader;

}

I did some debugging and found out that NullPointerException happens in AbstractDomainPath.java:226 while trying to add a sort specification
private void addSortSpecification(
            EmbeddableValuedModelPart embeddableValuedModelPart,
            QuerySpec ast,
            TableGroup tableGroup,
            String collation,
            String modelPartName,
            SortDirection sortOrder,
            NullPrecedence nullPrecedence,
            SqlAstCreationState creationState) {
        if ( embeddableValuedModelPart.getFetchableName()
                .equals( modelPartName ) || ELEMENT_TOKEN.equals( modelPartName ) ) {
            embeddableValuedModelPart.forEachSelectable(
                    (columnIndex, selection) -> {
                        addSortSpecification(
                                selection,
                                ast,
                                tableGroup,
                                collation,
                                sortOrder,
                                nullPrecedence,
                                creationState
                        );
                    }
            );
        }
        else {
            ModelPart subPart = embeddableValuedModelPart.findSubPart( modelPartName, null );
            addSortSpecification(
                    castNonNull( subPart.asBasicValuedModelPart() ), // LINE THAT THROWS NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION BECAUSE SUBPART IS NULL
                    ast,
                    tableGroup,
                    collation,
                    sortOrder,
                    nullPrecedence,
                    creationState
            );
        }
    }

Some information from the method above:

embeddableValuedModelPart.getFetchableName() = "userHierarchyPk"
modelPartName = "id"
ELEMENT_TOKEN = "$element$"

I tried to use @IdClass instead of EmbeddedId but it didn't work
Here's my pom's dependencies
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>23.3.0.23.09</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


Curious if you found an answer to this one? I'm seeing something very similar.
